# Can you include a html and css in an npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I’ve looked everywhere for this and cannot find a definitive answer. I’ve just started on the node package manager. If publishing a package for the community can it consist of html and css or is it purely for packages written in JavaScript?

Comment: Are you allowed to include it in the project files? Sure. There still needs to be a javascript file that is defined as the export otherwise your package won't really do anything.

Comment: Thanks Abir, if I installed the package into another project via the cli would the html page be created on my new project when showing up in my package.json file? Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For example, Bootstrap has an NPM package with their CSS in it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. So if I published it and then installed that npm package in my project folder to appear in my package.json file will a html page be created upon installation in the project in which I install it?

Comment: When I have enough points I will revisit this an mark up your answer. Thanks

Comment: No. But you can create project templates with npx, kind of like create-react-app does.

Comment: For sure, thanks)) @KevinGreetham

Comment: Oh ok. I see. So do npm packages normally just contain javascript? 
And the html file that is defaulted as index html that just creates the root div is created from an npx template? 

But a normal npm package , the html will not be created and we just require the Js code and build on top of it?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear there. The html page created in react I meant

Comment: Normally yes, they will usually just contain JS. The html file created in a standard create-react-app is created by running the "react-scripts build" command, not by the npx command.

Comment: How about if I exported a package which contained Js code creating new Dom elements and another person installed the package, would it then show up in their html page if the package was required in the project JS page?

Comment: If you create some functions which add elements to the page, then they install your package, import those functions, and call them within their own JS file, then yes. But why would you do that? Just use React at that point

Comment: Yes. I’ve been using react and vanilla is. I just want to get a better understanding of the inner workings around npm. This massively helped. Thanks.

Comment: @mstephen19, I've got a very similar question. I want to make a library that provides functions which you can use to turn any div on a page into a sort of "playground" where you can click to add elements and drag them around (my goal is certainly much more than this, but this is the basic functionality). So according to the above I can make an npm package with functions that create and manage such an interactive environment?

Comment: I’ve looked further into this. Yes you definitely could. When we export the functions from Js file with these capabilities it is open to use in our project. If you want the exported functions to create domElements then that’s exactly what it will do! You could set the classNames from within the exported function or pass the className into the function as an argument if you wanted to extend a html element that already exists in your html page! The second way would allow you to modify already existing elements!

Comment: But you wouldn’t export an html page. As it would appear in the node modules folder. You’d call your expected functions from inside your main Js working folder and manipulate the Dom from their!

Comment: @AcHybl see my comment. Hopefully it can help